# DotSpatial.Projections.Reproject.ReprojectPoints with Height?

Tags: gis, map-projections, dotspatial

https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/blob/master/Source/DotSpatial.Projections/Reproject.cs

Please can someone explain the Z array that the '.ReprojectPoints' command uses. Using the 'Earth from Space' projection: '+proj=ortho' I would like to reproject a point so that it is a specified distance above the planet surface - the idea is to draw a line from Point A on the ground to Point B on the ground that arcs into the sky and then comes down to earth again. Has anyone done this?